# CopyFromScreen doesn't it show the ellipsis in the image

Tags: forms, graphics, bitmap

I'm experimenting with this code.

I have a panel and a button at design time. Another button and panel are being generated dynamically. The resulting image I get is not showing the ellipsis, but showing the button, and I want to know why!?

```
    private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form3_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
        Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(50, 50, 100, 200);
        Ellipse el = new Ellipse();
        el.Rectangle = rect;
        //g.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
        g.DrawEllipse(pen, rect);

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap printscreen = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);

        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(printscreen as Image);

        graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, printscreen.Size);

        printscreen.Save(@"C:\Temp\temp.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the SendKeys.Send("{PRTSC}");
it is much simpler. Make sure to put at least of 2 second sleep before it:
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);